# Counting Principle - Dependent Events

Tags: probability

There are 7 red and 5 yellow fish in an aquarium. Three fish are randomly caught in a net. Find the probability that the fish were:

a)  All red

b)  Not all of the same color.

I have solved this question using the method for dependent events as follows:

a)  $\frac{7}{12} \cdot \frac{6}{11} \cdot \frac{5}{10} = \frac{210}{1320}$

b)  $1 - \left(\frac{7}{12} \cdot \frac{6}{11} \cdot \frac{5}{10} + \frac{5}{12} \cdot \frac{4}{11} \cdot \frac{3}{10}\right) = \frac{1170}{1320}$

Is it possible to use combinations to solve this question? If yes, how?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$

$$\frac{7 \choose 3}{12 \choose 3}$$

You can show that this equals what you did.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{7 \choose 3}{12 \choose 3}
&=\frac{\frac{7!}{3!4!}}{\frac{12!}{3!9!}}\\\\
&=\frac{7\cdot6\cdot5}{\color{red}{3\cdot2\cdot1}}\frac{\color{red}{3\cdot2\cdot1}}{12\cdot11\cdot10}\\\\
&=\frac{7}{12}\cdot\frac{6}{11}\cdot\frac{5}{10}
\end{align*}$$

$(b)$

$$1-\frac{7 \choose 3}{12 \choose 3}-\frac{5 \choose 3}{12 \choose 3}$$

Answer (score 1):

a) $$\frac{\binom73\binom50}{\binom{12}3}$$

b) $$1-\frac{\binom73\binom50}{\binom{12}3}-\frac{\binom70\binom53}{\binom{12}3}$$